# Objective C: Removing previous ui elements

Tags: objective-c, arrays, timer, uibutton

I'm producing a "brick" every second. When you tap it, it goes away. My problem is, when a second, or more, appear on the screen, tapping the previous one eliminates the most recent one, and can't be removed from the screen at all. The code I have is:

```
- (NSTimer *)getTimer{  
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:     @selector(produceBricks) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
return timer;
}


-(IBAction) tapBrick {
//remove last brick
[bricks[count] removeFromSuperview];

//add to score
count++;
NSString *scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];
score.text = scoreString;
}

-(void) produceBricks {
//determine x y coordinates
int xPos, yPos;
xPos = arc4random() % 250;
yPos = arc4random() % 370;

//create brick
bricks[count] = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos,yPos + 60,70,30)];  
[bricks[count] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[bricks[count] addTarget:self action:@selector(tapBrick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:bricks[count]];


}
```

I know it has to do with the `bricks[count] removeFromSuperview` line being count is always increasing. How would I reference to the brick in the array that's being clicked instead of the current one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views have a `tag` property for a reason — So you can identify views of the same type in the same view controller. Consider setting a unique tag for each of these bricks, and then removing the particular one you want to.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a `sender` argument, it'll automatically get set to the control which sent the action, so you can do something like the following:

```
-(IBAction) tapBrick:(id)sender {
    [sender removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the method `tapBrick:(UIButton *)brick` and you'll get a reference to the brick that was tapped as the argument.

Also, I strongly advise against using a C array for this. It's just asking for memory management trouble. Better to use an [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and make sure to follow the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). With the code you've posted, your brick objects will never be released, and instead they'll just keep eating memory until your app exhausts its supply.