# Objective C: Using tags

Tags: objective-c, tags, uibutton

I've been researching for the past few days and can't figure this out. I have a lot of buttons that do the same thing (disappear when clicked). I define each one with its own tag, but how do I determine which one is pressed?

```
-(IBAction) tapBrick{
int x = brick.tag;
NSLog(@"%d", x);


//remove last brick
[brick removeFromSuperview];

//add to score
count++;
NSString *scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];
score.text = scoreString;

//determine x y coordinates
int xPos, yPos;
xPos = arc4random() % 250;
yPos = arc4random() % 370;
}


-(void) produceBricks {
//determine x y coordinates
int xPos, yPos;
xPos = arc4random() % 250;
yPos = arc4random() % 370;

//create brick
brick = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos,yPos + 60,70,30)];  
[brick setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[brick setTag:i];
[brick addTarget:self action:@selector(tapBrick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
i++;
[self.view addSubview:brick];


}
```

Produce Bricks is called every 2 seconds by a timer.

Comment: You received answers on how to do this without tags in your last thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515592/objective-c-removing-previous-ui-elements

Comment: For the record, tags are a feature of the UIView class (and its derivatives), not an Objective C one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chris, if all you need to do is identify the button that's been pressed, simply change your method declaration to accept a `sender` parameter, and the caller (a `UIButton`, in this case) will supply a reference to itself. Create a `UIButton` pointer, and you'll be able to access the tag of the pressed button.

```
-(void) tapBrick:(id)sender {
    //this is the button that called your method.
    UIButton *theButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    int tag = theButton.tag;
    NSLog(@"%d", tag);

    [theButton removeFromSuperview];

    //rest of code  
}
```

(By the way, since you're creating the buttons with code, you don't need to declare a return value of `IBAction`. `IBAction` is the same as `void`, except that it tips off Interface Builder that you'll be connecting some `IBOutlet` to that particular method.)

Comment: I just did that, but it results in a runtime error. Do I change [brick removeFromSuperview] to be theButton or something?

Comment: yes, that's exactly right -- let me fill out the rest of the method.

Comment: Awesome thank you! So if I understand this correctly, by making this a sender, it's just going to send over the tag of whichever button is pressed?

Comment: actually it sends over a pointer to the button itself. We extracted the tag with that `int tag` assignment, just like we would from an object we'd just created. (You know you've got a pointer because of the `id` type. `id` just means, any type of object.)

Comment: Is it just me or is the NSLog wrong. I believe the x variable should actually be the tag variable created just beforehand.

Comment: Eric, sorry about that! Just made the fix.

Comment: That's Apple! It motivates everyone to develop even if they have no root knowledge of programming. Sorry about that.